# Validity of the static limit of a dielectric function

Tags: condensed-matter, dielectric, interactions

In general, the dielectric function $\epsilon(q,\omega)$ reflects the spatial and temporal response of a condensed matter system to an applied potential. If we put an electron into an electron sea, and ask how it interacts with another electron some distance away, this dielectric function tells us how that interaction is screened due to the sea around it. This I am comfortable with. I also understand that $q$ and $\omega$ are related to momentum and energy transfer in this interaction.

Question: when is it valid to consider only the static limit ($\omega=0$) of the dielectric function? I see this used often, in textbooks and in papers, but the authors never explain why it is that the are confident a static approximation is valid. My intuition tells me that if I consider a Coulomb interaction between two electrons in a many-body context, the fact that the bare interaction is time independent suggests static screening is valid. Is an argument like this valid, or is there something more formal?

Edit: okay, so I just found this problem that I asked a while ago that was never answered, and I eventually worked it out, so I may as well post an answer for anyone else that finds it just in case. Consider a potential $V(x,t)$. If we are dealing with a system of particles, all of which are moving a lot slower than the speed of light, it's a reasonable assumption to assume that the speed of light is infinite. ie Electron 1 and electron 2 both move with some speed $v_f$. They interact by the coulomb interaction, which is screened dynamically (that's why it's a function of $t$). But the interaction is mediated by photons, which travel at $c$. If $v_f\ll c$ then we can assume the most important physics is captured by assuming the interaction is actually instantaneous $V(x,t)=V(x)\delta(t)$. Take the Fourier transform of this from the time representation to the frequency representation, and the result is obviously the same as if $\omega=0$.